# Supervisor sentry-web exit status 1

Tags: ubuntu, supervisord

I'm having problems getting Sentry (https://www.getsentry.com - not enough rep for a link) running as a service using supervisor.
I can run Sentry in the command line and view it correctly in the browser but when it comes to supervisor I am completely in the dark.

I shall try and give all the details I can

**Initial user warning**

- By no means a server admin, just playing/learning in VirtualBox.
- Literally only just discovered supervisor from reading the Sentry documentation so I may well be making some obvious mistakes here.

**The setup:**

- Ubuntu server 11.10 (fresh install, VirtualBox)
- virtualenv with Sentry and its dependencies.
- supervisor

**Instructions followed**

- Supervisor with [vanilla ini file](http://supervisord.org/installing.html#creating-a-configuration-file)
- Sentry/supervisor [instructions](http://sentry.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart/index.html#running-sentry-as-a-service)

**My supervisor ini (Sentry section)**

```
[program:sentry-web]
directory=/root/.virtualenvs/sentry/
command= start http /root/.virtualenvs/sentry/bin/sentry
autostart=true
autorestart=true
redirect_stderr=true
```

**OK so here we go:**

When I run `supervisord -n` I get the following messages rather than a nice web interface to play with.

```
2012-04-12 23:48:09,024 CRIT Supervisor running as root (no user in config file)
2012-04-12 23:48:09,097 INFO RPC interface 'supervisor' initialized
2012-04-12 23:48:09,099 CRIT Server 'unix_http_server' running without any HTTP authentication checking
2012-04-12 23:48:09,100 INFO supervisord started with pid 17813
2012-04-12 23:48:10,126 INFO spawned: 'sentry-web' with pid 17816
2012-04-12 23:48:10,169 INFO exited: sentry-web (exit status 1; not expected)
2012-04-12 23:48:11,199 INFO spawned: 'sentry-web' with pid 17817
2012-04-12 23:48:11,238 INFO exited: sentry-web (exit status 1; not expected)
2012-04-12 23:48:13,269 INFO spawned: 'sentry-web' with pid 17818
2012-04-12 23:48:13,309 INFO exited: sentry-web (exit status 1; not expected)
2012-04-12 23:48:16,343 INFO spawned: 'sentry-web' with pid 17819
2012-04-12 23:48:16,389 INFO exited: sentry-web (exit status 1; not expected)
2012-04-12 23:48:17,394 INFO gave up: sentry-web entered FATAL state, too many start retries too quickly
```

`CRIT Supervisor running as root (no user in config file)` suggests a big problem, probably shouldn't be running this as root?

`CRIT Server 'unix_http_server' running without any HTTP authentication checking` Surely authentication is optional?

`INFO exited: sentry-web (exit status 1; not expected)` *sad face* here.  Google hasn't been much help yet.

Anyway, that is it as far as I know.  If anyone can help me that would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

**Update 1**

@Mark Henwood, thanks.

```
$ sudo /root/.virtualenvs/sentry/bin/sentry start http
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/sentry/bin/sentry", line 8, in <module>
    load_entry_point('sentry==3.8.2', 'console_scripts', 'sentry')()
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/sentry/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sentry/utils/runner.py", line 93, in main
    initializer=initialize_app,
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/sentry/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/logan/runner.py", line 120, in run_app
    raise ValueError("Configuration file does not exist. Use '%s init' to initialize the file." % runner_name)
ValueError: Configuration file does not exist. Use 'sentry init' to initialize the file.
```

Comment: What happens when you: $ sudo start http /root/.virtualenvs/sentry/bin/sentry ?

Comment: Thanks Mark.  Clearly it cant find the config file for whatever reason. I will move the virtualenvsout of /root/ (didnt mean for it to be there anyway) and see how that goes.

Comment: OK it was a mixture of permissions, typos and adding --config to the command but I am there now.  Thanks

Comment: @rockingskier: Could you post the solution as an answer? I have similar issue and your solution may be helpful also to others.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The --config option must be specified before the sentry subcommand, like so:

```
sentry --config=/somedir/sentry.conf.py start ....
```